# How does website send you data in chucks?

Tags: database

I just got curious one day, you know how Google sends you data in pages? Or like when you go to Twitter, Twitter will send you small amounts of feed at a time and as you scroll down it sends you more?

Since a standard SQL Limit is processed last meaning you have to query the whole table before selecting the 100th-130th feed before sending it to the user.

I was thinking if I were to run a full query every time a user scrolls to the bottom of a page. It's surely a very computationally heavy thing to do especially when the database is huge(e.g. social media). So I'm curious how do people send queried data in chunks to the user?

I tried googling it but failed I suspect that's due to the lack of knowledge for proper terms :/

Comment: _"Since a standard SQL `LIMIT` is processed last"_ - not necessarily.

Comment: _"meaning you have to query the whole table before selecting the 100th-130th feed before sending it to the user."_ - No, [that's not how `LIMIT` works](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html); you also need to consider that _even if_ a table-scan is necessary (and for fast-queries, it won't be) the DB engine uses the `LIMIT` to _stop_ reading any further source rows.

Comment: Also, Google doesn't use a SQL-based RDBMS to serve up search results.

Comment: So if i go to some random social media lets say does the server really query "SELECT * from Feed WHERE postedBy="friendUID1" and postedBy="friendUID2" ..... limit 100, 200"?

Comment: No, it won't. Most social-media sites don't use SQL-based RDBMS as anything more than a key-value-store and instead store chronological data in a denormalized form:  ([Reddit](https://kevin.burke.dev/kevin/reddits-database-has-two-tables/), [Facebook](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc13/atc13-bronson.pdf)). If you're really interested in this stuff, you should read the Facebook _TAO_ paper thoroughly - note that these techniques employed by systems with _hundreds of millions_ (or literally _billions_) of active users will not be appropriate for smaller systems.

Comment: Thank you so much, you really put a smile on my face for the whole day